SQL to get column value in GROUP BY based on value of another column
I'm struggling to articulate this problem in a concise title, but it will be easily explained with a simple example.
Say we have a single database table, named plum_tree_inspections, that records how many plums there were on a plum trees when inspected at a specific date. Imagine our table is like:



id
tree_id
date
height
plum_count




1
1234
12 Mar 2021
1.3
19


2
678
13 Mar 2021
2.8
16


3
1234
10 Mar 2022
1.5
26


4
678
11 Mar 2022
3.2
22


5
1234
20 Mar 2023
1.4
32


6
678
21 Mar 2023
3.6
20



Then I want to have a query that consolidates this table into a summary table (a view, in fact) that gives you info about each distinct tree. This should have columns for the earliest count date, latest count date, the maximum height the tree ever reached (maybe the top branch fell off in a storm one year), average plum count and the plum count from the most recent count.
I can use a simple function for all these columns, except the one to get the plum count from the most recent count. SQL would be like:
SELECT DISTINCT 
    tree_id,
    min(date) AS earliest_date,
    max(date) AS latest_date,
    max(height) AS max_height,
    avg(plum_count) AS avg_plum_count,
    ????? AS latest_plum_count
FROM plum_tree_inspections
GROUP BY tree_id

Is there some simple SQL for the ????? in the query above? Or does this need to be rewritten in a more involved query?
Note that the real world database I'm talking about has about a million records in the inspections table, so any solution needs to be pretty performant (but can be however complex it needs to be). Also, the DB is PostgreSQL

What RDBMS do you use?

@JonasMetzler good question. This is on PostgreSQL.

Here is an approach for you:
SELECT  
    tree_id,
    MIN(p.date) AS earliest_date,
    MAX(p.`date`) AS latest_date,
    MAX(p.height) AS max_height,
    AVG(p.plum_count) AS avg_plum_count,
    (SELECT p1.plum_count FROM `plum_tree_inspections` p1 WHERE p1.id=MAX(p.`id`)) AS latestCount
FROM plum_tree_inspections p
GROUP BY p.tree_id



I think two ways:
1.Subquery
    SELECT DISTINCT
tree_id,
min(date) AS earliest_date,
max(date) AS latest_date,
max(height) AS max_height,
avg(plum_count) AS avg_plum_count,
(
    SELECT date
    FROM plum_tree_inspections AS pti2
    WHERE pti2.tree_id = pti.tree_id
    AND pti2.plum_count = (SELECT MAX(plum_count) FROM plum_tree_inspections WHERE tree_id = pti.tree_id)
) AS latest_plum_count

FROM plum_tree_inspections AS pti
GROUP BY tree_id;
2.Window Functions
SELECT DISTINCT
tree_id,
min(date) AS earliest_date,
max(date) AS latest_date,
max(height) AS max_height,
avg(plum_count) AS avg_plum_count,
MAX(CASE WHEN plum_count = MAX(plum_count) OVER (PARTITION BY tree_id) THEN date END) AS latest_plum_count

FROM plum_tree_inspections
GROUP BY tree_id;
Both methods achieve the same result of finding the date corresponding to the max(plum_count) for each tree_id group.

Both queries are invalid and can't be executed. Please try out possible solutions before proposing them as answer.

SELECT 
    pt.tree_id,
    MIN(pt.date) AS earliest_date,
    MAX(pt.date) AS latest_date,
    MAX(pt.height) AS max_height,
    AVG(pt.plum_count) AS avg_plum_count,
    pt2.plum_count AS latest_plum_count
FROM 
    plum_tree_inspections pt
JOIN (
    SELECT 
        tree_id,
        MAX(date) AS latest_date
    FROM 
        plum_tree_inspections
    GROUP BY 
        tree_id
) AS latest_dates ON pt.tree_id = latest_dates.tree_id AND pt.date = latest_dates.latest_date
JOIN 
    plum_tree_inspections pt2 ON pt.tree_id = pt2.tree_id AND pt.date = pt2.date
GROUP BY 
    pt.tree_id;

